# Laravel ErrorException No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, putty

I have uploaded my Laravel project on ubuntu server via putty terminal.
Composer installed on server machine but when i run any artisan command it gives an error.

```
$ php artisan serve
     ErrorException
    
      require(/var/www/html/healthapi.fynity.in/routes/api/v1/api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The `api.php` is already there but i don't know why this error comes. Tried all the solutions from google.

Comment: Spelling is ok (i.e. upper case vs. lower case for some segment of that path, maybe `api` or `v1` has to be capitalised somehow)?

Comment: @Prathamesh Did you tried `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG tried all the artisan command, but didn't work, the project run perfectly on my windows system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

---

You may have changed something earlier such as the name or the path of the file.

**Solution:**

---

First of all, you use the following command to clear all configs.

```
$ php artisan config:clear
```

Then, you run again the following command.

```
$ php artisan serve
```

**Update (2021/01/07)**:

You got the following error:

```
ErrorException require(/var/www/html/healthapi.fynity.in/routes/api/v1/api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteFileRegistrar.php:35 31
```

It seems that the library is not fully installed. You should update the library with the following command:

```
$ composer update
```

Then, you run again the following command:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

Comment: tried it and got an error,    ErrorException

  require(/var/www/html/healthapi.fynity.in/routes/api/v1/api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteFileRegistrar.php:35
     31▕     public function register($routes)
     32▕     {
     33▕         $router = $this->router;
     34▕
  ➜  35▕         require $routes;
     36▕     }
     37▕ }